# C function to remove a directory

Tags: c, linux, directory

How to remove a directory and all its content from a C program on a Linux machine?
I managed to create a directory with `mkdir("path", 0700);` and now I wonder if there is a similar way to remove it and all its subfolders and files.

Comment: In POSIX, there isn't a way to remove a subdirectory and all its contents — no.  There is a way to remove an empty subdirectory (the inverse of create an empty subdirectory) — yes: it is [`rmdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rmdir.html).  To remove contents too, investigate 
[`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html).  There might be a Linux-specific function, too.  Or you can run `rm -fr /the/directory` via `system()` or equivalent.

Comment: *"and all its subfolders and files"* -- You have to recursively delete its contents if it is not empty. I don't believe the C standard library has a built-in way to perform a recursive delete.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is by calling `rm -r` with `system()` or `fork/exec`.

Comment: @Barmar Easiest? Probably. But I'd be hesitant to use this approach in anything but a simple toy/demo program.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers: the solution pointed out by @Barmar actually works.

Comment: @cdhowie why should I avoid this approach?

Comment: @cabbasisi: Because if you aren't careful, `rm -fr /home/user/Docs & Photos` to remove the `Docs & Photos` directory (singular — name with spaces and shell metacharacters) doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, that's why I mentioned fork/exec, it avoids shell parsing issues.

Comment: @cabbasisi It seems silly to depend on an external tool for something that is fairly trivially implemented in C.